# Why does str() in a for loop not output elements in a list

Tags: python

I’m trying to understand why the str() method doesn’t output the elements in the list when using for loop:

```
li_1 = ['hi', 'hello', 'howdy']

for i in li_1:
    str(i)
```

Whereas the str() method in the following list comprehension does output the elements:

```
[str(j) for j in li_1]
```

Comment: You're just throwing away the values returned by `str` in the first case.

Comment: `str()` is not supposed to output anything, it converts an argument to a string and returns that string.

Comment: Are you using an interactive console? In the interactive console, if your input is an expression, the interpreter will print out the result automatically after calculation. If you use some statements such as for or if, it will not print them for you. You need to print them manually.

Comment: Why are you calling *str()* anyway? The values passed to it are already strings

Comment: You do know _The `str()` is used to convert the specified value into a string_ right? And list comprehension output expression is basically `append()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Because str does not print anything its just return value so you can store in a variable or directly print returning value using print. Try below code

```
li_1 = ['hi', 'hello', 'howdy']

for i in li_1:
  print(str(i))
```

or

```
li_1 = ['hi', 'hello', 'howdy']
[print(str(j)) for j in li_1]
```

Answer (score 0):

[str()](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/functions/str.html) method maps input to a string. In your case there is no reason to use it. But if you want to use it you have to first assign the output.
Example:

```
digit = str(1)
print(digit)
```

In your case you probably want to print each value from the list like this:

```
li_1 = [‘hi’, ‘hello’, ‘howdy’] 
for word in li_1: 
    print(word)
```

Or just:

```
print(*li_1)
```

Even if you mix types in your list. The print statement handles this:

```
li_1 = ["hi", "hello", "howdy", 232]
for word in li_1:
    print(word)
```

Output:

```
hi
hello
howdy
232
```